# Showing hamburger instead back arrow (just after the rotation)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, toolbar

**I have activity with fragments  a,b and inside onCreateView(this fragments) i use** 
*inside fragment A:*

```
((BaseActivity)getActivity()).resetToolbarNavigation(false);
```

*and from fragment a open b fragment:*

```
((BaseActivity)getActivity()).resetToolbarNavigation(true);
```

**And inside activity realize method resetToolbarNavigation**

```
    public void resetToolbarNavigation(boolean backNavigationEnabled) {
        mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(backNavigationEnabled);
        if (backNavigationEnabled) {
            mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            initNavigation();
            syncState();
        }
    }
```

***All work fine but when i change orientation my back arrow convert to namburger.***

Comment: activity gets recreated on rotation so you should save instance of your fragment

Comment: @VivekMishra can you give more info)

Comment: search for it as it can't be explained here

Comment: @VivekMishra i know how save some value, but fragment i dont know.
Can you give huperlink about this topic?

Comment: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/best-approach-to-keep-android-fragment-state/en

Comment: @VivekMishra it doesnt help me, my back arrow again morf to hamburger, pls help if you can...